# Selecting only one random key-value pair from a particular attribute in JSON schema

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get a new JSON schema from the given JSON schema with only one key-value pair chosen randomly from the "properties" attribute. It should also have the "title" and "type" attributes.

```
{ "title": "animals object",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     'cat': 'meow',
     'dog': 'woof',
     'cow': 'moo',
     'sheep': 'baaah',
     'bird': 'tweet'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get a random number between 0-4 that can be used to get the `properties` key randomly and use that key to add it in the `properties` of new JSON object:

```js
var jsonSchema = { "title": "animals object",
   "type": "object",
   "properties":
     {
     'cat': 'meow',
     'dog': 'woof',
     'cow': 'moo',
     'sheep': 'baaah',
     'bird': 'tweet'
     }
};
var newJSON = { "title": "animals object",
   "type": "object",
   "properties":{}
};

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var randomPropertyKey = Object.keys(jsonSchema.properties)[randomNumber];
newJSON.properties[randomPropertyKey] = jsonSchema.properties[randomPropertyKey];
console.log(newJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
var originalJson = {
      "title": "animals object",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        'cat': 'meow',
        'dog': 'woof',
        'cow': 'moo',
        'sheep': 'baaah',
        'bird': 'tweet'
      }
    };

    // deep copy of the json object
    var jsonCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalJson)); 
    //gets a random property of a collection
    var propToKeep = pickRandomProperty(jsonCopy.properties);
   
    //deletes all properties of the copied collection except the randomly chosen one
    for (var key in jsonCopy.properties) {
          if(key.toString() !== propToKeep) {
            delete jsonCopy.properties[key]
        }    
    }

    function pickRandomProperty(obj) {
      var result;
      var count = 0;
      
      for (var key in obj){
        //if there's only one left, take it.
        if (Math.random() < 1 / ++count){
          result = key;
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
    console.log("copy", jsonCopy);
    console.log("original", originalJson);
```